# Objective-C AirPrint UIImageView image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, airprint

I am trying to print some text from a UITextView, together with one picture from a UIImageView. I have searched for some tutorial on the web and I succeeded to print the text from the UITextView, but I have not yet found a way to print an image with it. 
The UIImageView I want to print is qrImageView and the UITextView is called qrNoteTextView.
I use the following code to print the TextView:

```
- (IBAction)qrPrint:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"print action");
        [self.qrNoteTextView resignFirstResponder];
        NSMutableString *printBody = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@", self.qrNoteTextView.text, self.qrImageView.image];

        [printBody appendFormat:@"\nCreated using ..."];

        UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
        pic.delegate = self;

        UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
        printInfo.jobName = self.qrNoteTextView.text;
        pic.printInfo = printInfo;

        UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *textFormatter = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithText:printBody];
        textFormatter.startPage = 0;
        textFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0); // 1 inch margins
        textFormatter.maximumContentWidth = 6 * 72.0;
        pic.printFormatter = textFormatter;
        pic.showsPageRange = YES;

        void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
        ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
            if (!completed && error) {
                NSLog(@"Printing could not complete because of error: %@", error);
            }
        };

        [pic presentFromBarButtonItem:self.qrNoteTextView animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Convert  UITextView content into NSData and try to print it after encode it with UTF8 format. May it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Convert UITextView content into NSData and try to print it after encode it with UTF8 format. May it will help you.

Or you can convert it in Base64 for print. You can use following code for print a text and image.

NSMutableString *msgBody = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    [msgBody appendString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Printed from MyApp"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]];

```
                       //Embedding the image
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Private Documents", [paths objectAtIndex:0]];

                       NSArray *arrayOfSignatureTitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image0.png", @"image1.png", @"image2.png", @"image3.png", nil];

                       for (NSString *imageName in arrayOfSignatureTitles)
{
    NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:appFile];

    if (imageData != nil)
    {
        [Base64 initialize];
        NSString *base64String = [Base64 encode:imageData];
        [msgBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"  ",base64String]];
    }
}
                       [msgBody appendString:@""];

                       UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
                       pic.delegate = self;

                       UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
                       printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
                       printInfo.jobName = @"NarrativePro";
                       pic.printInfo = printInfo;

                       UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter *textFormatter = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithMarkupText:msgBody];
                       textFormatter.startPage = 0;
                       textFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0); // 1 inch margins
                       textFormatter.maximumContentWidth = 6 * 72.0;
                       pic.printFormatter = textFormatter;
                       pic.showsPageRange = YES;

                       void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error)
{
    if (!completed && error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Printing could not complete because of error: %@", error);
    }
};

                       [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Comment: I converted the UITextView and the UIImageView to NSData and put those together in a NSMutableData. But how do I get this NSMutableData to be printed?

Comment: You can use following code for add a image on UITextView 

'UIImage* onions = [self thumbnailOfImageWithName:@"onion" extension:@"jpg"];

NSTextAttachment* onionatt = [NSTextAttachment new];
onionatt.image = onions;
onionatt.bounds = CGRectMake(0,-5,onions.size.width,onions.size.height);
NSAttributedString* onionattchar = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:onionatt];

NSRange r = [[mas string] rangeOfString:@"Onions"];
[mas insertAttributedString:onionattchar atIndex:(r.location + r.length)];

self.tv.attributedText = mas;

Comment: I added the printer code for both text and image print. if its work please but up the answer.

Comment: You need to download Base64 files and than add these files in your project code. use this code in a method.

Comment: I am getting a lot of errors when I try to fit the code in. It doesn't recognize 'mas' and 'tv' and 'thumbnailOfImagWithName.

Comment: don't forget to add 

NSMutableString *msgBody = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""]; [msgBody appendString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"Printed from MyApp"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]];

Comment: It does not recognize Base64, how could I solve that?